# Is it possible to kill node.js website on some idle time and re-run it on the next request, automatically?

Tags: node.js, linux, iis, next.js

IIS has an amazing feature that is very suitable for hosting providers.

When a website has no visitors (idle time), IIS automatically kills the process, and releases RAM and other resources.

On the next request, IIS first starts a process and then serves that request.

This means that on a server with limited amount of resources, you can host more low-traffic websites (high-density).

Now we're migrating to next.js. When we deploy a website, we use `npm start` to run it. However, this means that each website would take 200 or more MBs of the server's RAM constantly.

Is there a way to configure next.js to behave like IIS? To automatically shut down on a period of inactivity and then automatically load on the next request.

Answer (score 0):

If you host Node.js web apps via HttpPlatformHandler, then you get what you wanted,

https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#nextjs

Comment: my bad, we're using Linux and we do not host on IIS anymore. So, `HttpPlatformHandler` which is a IIS module can not help us. Thank you.